# Accord pluriel participe présent

Tags: accord, pluriel, participe-présent

Le participe présent fonctionne comme un adverbe invariable sauf s'il est employé comme un adjectif, et s'accorde alors en genre et en nombre avec son sujet.

Dans la phrase :

> Il a réalisé plusieurs objets de différents types, répondant à ses besoins de créativité.

Est-ce que *répondant* s'écrit *répondant* ou *répondants* ?

Est-ce que les deux solutions sont possibles, si l'on considère **que soit les objets** répondent, soit **lui**, répond à son propre besoin ?

Comment: La virgule précédant « répondant » n'a pas lieu d'être.

Comment: @jlliagre Est-ce possible que la virgule peut (même doit?) y être pour mieux capter le 2eme sens proposé par l’OP («soit lui, répond à son propre besoin») = «Répondant à ses besoins …, il a réalisé plusieurs objets …»? Il me semble que SANS virgule, «répondant» modifie clairement le nom pluriel ‘objets’ (espèce d’adjective oui, mais comme ‘expression verbale,’ reste invariable suivant la bonne réponse d’Iside) mais AVEC  virgule, «répondant» modifie (pas «Il», comme propose l’OP) plutôt le verbe «réaliser» carrément comme adverbe  (de cause?) et donc reste invariable. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Sauf cas très particuliers, le participe présent reste invariable. Une manière de s'en rendre compte est d'essayer de la mettre au féminin :

> Il a réalisé plusieurs machines, répondant à ses besoins

On pourrait dire :

> Il a réalisé plusieurs objets qui répondent à ses besoins

Dans ce cas pas d'accord.

Answer (score 2):

Dans votre phrase, répondant s'écrit bien comme vous l'avez mis.

Ce sont les objets qui répondent aux besoins de "**lui**".

Pour qu'un verbe au participe présent soit accordé, il faut qu'il ait la valeur d'adjectif. Exemple : Environner -> Environnant (signifie être aux environs)

- Nous allons dans les champs **environnants**.
- Les champs **environnant** la ville.

Answer (score 2):

Dans cet exemple, «répondant à ses besoins» est le participe présent de l'expression verbale «répondre aux besoins de». Dans ce cas-ci «répondant» restera toujours un verbe au participe présent  et il est hors de question de l'accorder. Il en va de même pour toutes les autres expressions verbales.

Autre exemple: «Les paragraphes correspondant aux questions 2 et 3 de l'examen se trouvent dans le premier chapitre du livre». Expression «correspondre à».

«Malgré mes recherches, je n'ai jamais pu trouver les concepts correspondants». «Correspondant» utilisé comme adjectif.

Si nous avions deux Charles Trénet, nous aurions deux fous chantants. Bien différent de deux fous chantant bien ou  deux fous chantant haut et fort.

Answer (score 2):

Les participes présents ne s'accordent pas normalement pas (il y a une série de locutions figées où ils le sont). Les adjectifs verbaux le font.  Ils ont généralement la même orthographe (mais à nouveau il y a une série d'exceptions, certains sont en -ent par exemple).  Avec la même forme encore, il y a les gérondifs (introduits normalement par *en*, ils ont une fonction de complément de temps, de manière, ...)

Pour reconnaître les uns des autres, il faut savoir que les adjectifs verbaux étant des adjectifs n'ont pas de COD ou de COI (ce qui permet de répondre à ta question ici, il y a un COI *à ses besoins*).  Les adjectifs verbaux ont pu aussi acquérir des sens en plus de ceux du verbe (un *billet payant* bien souvent ne paye rien du tout).

En l'absence de compléments et de changement de sens, il peut y avoir une certaine ambiguïté.  Un truc pour les personnes dont le français est la langue maternelle est de faire la négation, celle d'un adjectif va être construit en *non adj*, celle d'un participe présent en *ne pp pas* (ici ce serait *ne répondant pas à ses besoins* plutôt que *non répondant à ses besoins*).